# What is size 2 pasta?

Tags: pasta, shopping

I have a recipe requesting pasta #2 as an ingredient.  What is pasta #2?  I searched in several places but found nothing useful.

Comment: Pasta manufacturers do sometimes refer to their product by number (either indicating die size, the order they developed the shapes in, or possibly their favorite lotto numbers), but Adele is most likely correct. If the recipe says "2#", that means two pounds. (In American English, "#" is sometimes called the "pound sign", and using it as an alternative to "lbs." is very common in cooking.) If it's "#2", that probably requires more background information (where did you get the recipe) to answer.

Comment: If it means pounds that's a lot of pasta - enough for 9 or 10 people.

Comment: Any chance you could post a scan and/or picture (even from a cell phone camera is fine) of the recipe? Seeing exactly what's on the page would help figure out what its saying... Unless its an online recipe, in which case please link to it.

Comment: Would this maybe help?

http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/4815/whats-the-numbering-system-for-spaghetti-and-does-it-matter

Answer (score 5):

#2 pasta is a very large noodled pasta with a hole in the center running the length of the noodle. It's like a spaghetti noodle only much thicker around. Used often in Greek dishes and esp with the mizythra cheese and browned butter recipe. It is very difficult to find.

Comment: [This recipe](http://www.greekzoe.com/searchresults.asp?cat=1839) seems to support this.  It lists bucatini and ziti as possible substitutes.  It is also worth noting that Greek pasta makers Melissa and Misko both describe this type of pasta as "no. 2".  Perciatelli may also be similar.

Comment: @JTL : Amazon lists the #2 Misko, which looks like bucatini.  They have other numbers, too ... one of them mentions "#5 is thinner/smaller than the #2 and #3 macaroni noodles"

Answer (score 3):

Is it possible that the recipe calls for two *pounds* of pasta?  I have seen recipes where the # symbol is used as a notation of pounds.

Answer (score 2):

This is most probably referring to the size of pasta of a certain type.

But you shoul be more detailed in your question, saying the type of pasta you refer to or the source where you got the receipt from.

If the pasta are noodles then you can bet it that they are talking about the size of pasta.

Pasta exist of many different kinds (at least here in italy), so pasta #2 is to us like saying "a car with comfortable chairs"...quite generic :-)

This [link might](http://wiki.answers.com/Q/What_does_the_number_6_or_number_8_mean_on_spaghetti_packages) help.

Answer (score 0):

Buccatini pasta is a #2 pasta. Saw this referred to in Symon Cooking Outdoors program as he was making a greek pasta dish.