# How do I tell bucatelli pasta size and thickness

Tags: pasta

I am trying to find Bucatini pasta.  I don't want the really thick one...I have seen it with #14, #16, etc.Which ine is the smaller diameter?

Comment: Bucatini and perciatelli are the same basic pasta -- a long, thin rod with a hole down the center and a bit thicker than spaghetti. Although I can't point to a definition of the two, from what I've seen bucatini is the thinner one. The numbers don't mean anything.

Answer (score 3):

See:  [What's the numbering system for spaghetti and does it matter?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/4815/whats-the-numbering-system-for-spaghetti-and-does-it-matter)

The number assigned to pastas is particular to individual manufacturers.   You would need their data sheet, if they offer one, to know the details based on their product numbers.

On the other hand, many pastas are packaged so that you can see product, and make comparisons.   If that is not the case, pasta is not terribly expensive--you could buy a couple of different ones and see which one you like.