# recipe asks for fideo pasta number 0 thickness

Tags: pasta, thickness

i have a recipe that lists fideo pasta 0 thickness for the pasta. where can I find this pasta?

Comment: Odds are, it's a very thin noodle.  see https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/4815/67

Answer (score 1):

Angel hair pasta is a suitable substitute for fideo.